# Mover processo para outro desktop

Tags: delphi

Imagina um cenário em que eu tenho o `desktop` padrão do `windows`, e eu crio outro `desktop`, depois preciso mover a minha aplicação para o segundo. Atualmente eu crio esta aplicação no outro, mas estou tendo problemas com isso.

O que eu preciso é algum comando que mova a minha aplicação atual para o segundo `desktop`, neste momento o que estou a usar é o comando `CreateProcess`, e faço da seguinte forma:

```
 FillChar(sinfo, SizeOf(sinfo), 0);
 sinfo.cb := SizeOf(sinfo);
 sinfo.lpDesktop := PChar('desktop_aplic');
 CreateProcess(pchar(Application.ExeName), nil, nil, nil, False, 0, nil, nil, sinfo, pinfo);
```

Existe um jeito de eu mover a aplicação ao invés de criar uma nova?

Comment: Você se refere ao recurso de múltiplas Áreas de Trabalho do Windows 10?

Comment: @rodorgas, na verdade não, pelo próprio DELPHI tem como você criar novos desktops, eu tenho o nome dele, mais queria mover minha aplicação para ele ao invés de criar um processo novo.